# Arbitrary OpenGL Errors in empty Game Loop

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I'm struggeling to find the mistake in my code. As fas as I am concerned, there shouldn't even be one...
On Runtime I'm getting various errors all pointing towards deprecated Fixed Function calls. 
Now here's the kicker. For Test purposes I removed all draw-calls and other OpenGl commands apart from some initializing calls. The program still prints out a load of errors (eventough not a single call is made)

I'm running on Windows 10 with an AMD Radeon R9 270, Driver Version: 15.201.1151-150821a-188665E
I'm using glfw-3.0.4 and glew 1.10.0

Here's the code to initialize everything.
    bool Application::initWindow()
    {
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        Console::writeError("GLFW Init failed!");
        return false;
    }
    #if _DEBUG
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_DEBUG_CONTEXT, GL_TRUE);
    #endif

```
// Set window hints
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_REFRESH_RATE, 60);


window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Window", nullptr, nullptr);

if (!window) {
    Console::writeError("Creating Window failed!");
    return false;
}
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
{
    Console::writeError("Glew Init failed!");
    return false;

}
// Glew produces an arbitrary error therefore ignore it
glGetError();
DebugContext::initDebugContext();


glClearColor(0.49f, 0.73f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

return true;
}
```

Here's the code that is called on runtime: 
    void Application::run() {

```
float lastTime = 0;
auto time = glfwGetTime();
float deltaT = (float)(time - lastTime);
lastTime = (float)time;

// Game Loop
while (isRunning && !glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);     

// Calculate Frame Time
    time = glfwGetTime();
    deltaT = float(time - lastTime);
    lastTime = time;

    glfwPollEvents();
    //Console::writeMessage("FrameTime: " + std::to_string(deltaT));


    //Mouseinteraction
    //handleMouseMove(window, deltaT);

    //CameraControll
    // cameraController->update(deltaT);

    // Upate Scene
    //scene->update(deltaT / 1000);

    // Render Scene
    //renderer->draw(scene);


    glfwSwapBuffers(window);

}
Console::writeMessage("Application::run() finished");
Destroy();
}
```

The frame gets colored correctly with the clear color.
And finally here's the output of my error handling class for a single frame. This error keep occuring every single frame. The strange thing is, that these errors do not occur on the first frame but somewhat after 10-15 seconds.

```
OpenGL Error: Using glGetIntegerv in a Core context with parameter <pname> and enum '0xbb1' which was removed from Core OpenGL (GL_INVALID_ENUM) [Source = API, Type = Error, Severity = High, ID = 3200]
OpenGL Error: Using glGetIntegerv in a Core context with parameter <pname> and enum '0xd3b' which was removed from Core OpenGL (GL_INVALID_ENUM) [Source = API, Type =     Error, Severity = High, ID = 3200]
OpenGL Error: glPushClientAttrib has been removed from OpenGL Core context (GL_INVALID_OPERATION) [Source = API, Type = Error, Severity = High, ID = 3203]
OpenGL Error: Using glGetIntegerv in a Core context with parameter <pname> and enum '0xbb0' which was removed from Core OpenGL (GL_INVALID_ENUM) [Source = API, Type = Error, Severity = High, ID = 3200]
OpenGL Error: Using glGetIntegerv in a Core context with parameter <pname> and enum '0xd35' which was removed from Core OpenGL (GL_INVALID_ENUM) [Source = API, Type = Error, Severity = High, ID = 3200]
OpenGL Error: glPushAttrib has been removed from OpenGL Core context (GL_INVALID_OPERATION) [Source = API, Type = Error, Severity = High, ID = 3203]
OpenGL Error: Using glGetIntegerv in a Core context with parameter <pname> and enum '0xba4' which was removed from Core OpenGL (GL_INVALID_ENUM) [Source = API, Type = Error, Severity = High, ID = 3200]
OpenGL Error: Using glGetIntegerv in a Core context with parameter <pname> and enum '0xd38' which was removed from Core OpenGL (GL_INVALID_ENUM) [Source = API, Type = Error,     Severity = High, ID = 3200]
OpenGL Error: glMatrixMode has been removed from OpenGL Core context (GL_INVALID_OPERATION) [Source = API, Type = Error, Severity = High, ID = 3203]
OpenGL Error: glPushMatrix has been removed from OpenGL Core context (GL_INVALID_OPERATION) [Source = API, Type = Error, Severity = High, ID = 3203]
OpenGL Error: Using glGetIntegerv in a Core context with parameter <pname> and enum '0xba3' which was removed from Core OpenGL (GL_INVALID_ENUM) [Source = API, Type = Error,     Severity = High, ID = 3200]
OpenGL Error: Using glGetIntegerv in a Core context with parameter <pname> and enum '0xd36' which was removed from Core OpenGL (GL_INVALID_ENUM) [Source = API, Type = Error,     Severity = High, ID = 3200]
OpenGL Error: glMatrixMode has been removed from OpenGL Core context (GL_INVALID_OPERATION) [Source = API, Type = Error, Severity = High, ID = 3203]
OpenGL Error: glPushMatrix has been removed from OpenGL Core context (GL_INVALID_OPERATION) [Source = API, Type = Error, Severity = High, ID = 3203]
OpenGL Error: Using glDisable in a Core context with parameter <cap> and enum '0xb50' which was removed from Core OpenGL (GL_INVALID_ENUM) [Source = API, Type = Error,     Severity = High, ID = 3200]
OpenGL Error: Using glEnable in a Core context with parameter <cap> and enum '0xbc0' which was removed from Core OpenGL (GL_INVALID_ENUM) [Source = API, Type = Error,     Severity = High, ID = 3200]
OpenGL Error: glAlphaFunc has been removed from OpenGL Core context (GL_INVALID_OPERATION) [Source = API, Type = Error, Severity = High, ID = 3203]
OpenGL Error: Using glDisable in a Core context with parameter <cap> and enum '0xde0' which was removed from Core OpenGL (GL_INVALID_ENUM) [Source = API, Type = Error,         Severity = High, ID = 3200]
OpenGL Error: Using glEnable in a Core context with parameter <cap> and enum '0xde1' which was removed from Core OpenGL (GL_INVALID_ENUM) [Source = API, Type = Error,         Severity = High, ID = 3200]
OpenGL Error: glMatrixMode has been removed from OpenGL Core context (GL_INVALID_OPERATION) [Source = API, Type = Error, Severity = High, ID = 3203]
OpenGL Error: glLoadIdentity has been removed from OpenGL Core context (GL_INVALID_OPERATION) [Source = API, Type = Error, Severity = High, ID = 3203]
OpenGL Error: glOrtho has been removed from OpenGL Core context (GL_INVALID_OPERATION) [Source = API, Type = Error, Severity = High, ID = 3203]
OpenGL Error: glMatrixMode has been removed from OpenGL Core context (GL_INVALID_OPERATION) [Source = API, Type = Error, Severity = High, ID = 3203]
OpenGL Error: glLoadIdentity has been removed from OpenGL Core context (GL_INVALID_OPERATION) [Source = API, Type = Error, Severity = High, ID = 3203]
OpenGL Error: glMatrixMode has been removed from OpenGL Core context (GL_INVALID_OPERATION) [Source = API, Type = Error, Severity = High, ID = 3203
OpenGL Error: glPopMatrix has been removed from OpenGL Core context (GL_INVALID_OPERATION) [Source = API, Type = Error, Severity = High, ID = 3203]
OpenGL Error: glMatrixMode has been removed from OpenGL Core context (GL_INVALID_OPERATION) [Source = API, Type = Error, Severity = High, ID = 3203]
OpenGL Error: glPopMatrix has been removed from OpenGL Core context (GL_INVALID_OPERATION) [Source = API, Type = Error, Severity = High, ID = 3203]
OpenGL Error: glPopAttrib has been removed from OpenGL Core context (GL_INVALID_OPERATION) [Source = API, Type = Error, Severity = High, ID = 3203]
OpenGL Error: glPopClientAttrib has been removed from OpenGL Core context (GL_INVALID_OPERATION) [Source = API, Type = Error, Severity = High, ID = 3203]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks,

Jimmy

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You said 'empty game loop', but it's clear, that it is not *empty*. You created context with **core** profile and use deprecated features, that are no supported. Ask google about "opengl deprecation".

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek: Well, in the code which was posted, the loop is almost empty, and none of the functions from the error log are called.

Comment: exactly! With empty I mean I commented all opengl calls and only call clear to show its working. The point is that I do not use any of those functions but still get errors...

Comment: Alright after some painful debugging I found in the stack trace hat the method were called by an external program, and after some more research i discovered that AMDs Gaming Ecolved might have to do something with that. I didn't even now that this program was still running in the background so I quit it and since then the errors are gone.